# How do you link form action to a view method?

Tags: python, django

In my rendered `index.html`, I have:

```
<form action="???" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In my `views.py`, I have:

```
class weather(base.TemplateView):
    # Generates the above html

def get_hours(request):
     # do something with request.Post
     return shortcuts.render(request, "index.html", {"form": form})
```

How do I make the form action call the `get_hours`? I want to post to the same page the form is on so the page won't refresh and will display the results on the same page.

Comment: something like `action="/foo/bar/get-hours/"`?

Comment: moreover, if you want to restrict the *page refresh*, ajax will be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found it.

```
class weather(base.TemplateView):   
     .....
     def post(request, *args, **kwargs):            
          # do something with request.Post
          return shortcuts.render(request, "weather/index.html", {"form": form})
```